# Creation of array of gui components using netbeans gui builder

Tags: java, arrays

I have been finding it difficult to create an array in netbeans because I am using the gui builder. Netbeans does not allow me to add any code to the guarded code region.  I have searched online for a solution but to no avail.  I created the array after initcomponent but it is throwing an illegal forward reference error because the array is defined before the gui components.  My issue now is i want to make the array a class variable, i don't want to declare it as a local variable to a method.  What can I do?

Comment: Singh, I just did it, it worked fine.. I was able to edit the code.. Here lies the problem, the array declared is giving me error "cannot find symbol"  after running on netbeans.. This is the code i used, i want to actually create an array of checkboxes.. JCheckBox [] JC = {jCheckBox1,JCheckBox2} ;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your problem (sounds like your coding structure problem to me). But I will still tell you how to edit netbeans code.

First go into your project folder (Default is: `C:/users/username/Documents/Netbeans Projects/ProjectName`

Then go inside the `src` folder. And there you have your source code. All `.java` files are your source code (there are also `.form` files, but dont mess with them. Thats netbeans GUI builder data you dont want messing with).

Open the java source code with any text editor, edit and save your code, open netbeans and refresh it (right click project name and `refresh`). You have changed the *unchangeable* code.

Comment: _unchangeable_ is a misnomer. It's rather _generated code_. Make any change in the GUI Builder and all your 'changes' are gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array field *after* the variable declaration region. Place the caret at the closing `}` of the class and you can create lines below the generated region.